# Android. JSON parser return null in my new module

Tags: java, android, json, module, gson

I created a new module in my project where I need parse JSON file, but parser(I used GSON) returns null. Before the module was created in the project, the parser worked. Json string from file is correct.

file.json

```
{"link":"https://google.com/","title":"Google"}
```

how I parse

```
BrowserLink browserLink = gson.fromJson(json, BrowserLink.class);
```

BrowserLink.java

```
public class BrowserLink {
    private String title;

    private String link;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "title: " + title + "; link: " + link;
    }
}
```

Result from browserLink.toString()

```
title = title: null; link: null
```

What should I do with the module for work parser?

Comment: nothing wrong with your code
`new Gson().fromJson("{\"link\":\"https://google.com/\",\"title\":\"Google\"}",BrowserLink.class)`
worked as expected for me. do you configure your `gson` with any custom setting?

Comment: @harsh, still not working. I'm starting to think that the problem with the configuration of my module or app module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after Android Studio and Gradle update
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring